# Libimobiledevice. iOS. Access to Containers\Shared\AppGroup folder

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, ios8

I use Libimobiledevice library.

Can I get access to "var\mobile\Containers\Shared\AppGroup{app id}" folder?
I actually used house_arrest client to access Containers\Data\Application folder, but in iOS 8x created new shared folder with app data.

So, please help, can I get access to Shared\AppGroup folder using libimobiledevice?